# How should I fix the XCode 9 Beta 2 ARKit spritekit demo project so that it works

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, arkit

I created a new ARKit SpriteKit demo project using Xcode's new project template and saw on a tutorial https://dev.to/osterbergjordan/arkit--vision-an-intriguing-combination that I should replace this in the `viewDidLoad`.  The blog author didn't know why this line should be replaced. Note that I didn't do any of the other changes in their blog - just kept the vanilla ARKit starter project with the alien invader labels on touch.

```
//Load the SKScene from 'Scene.sks'
if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "Scene") {
    sceneView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

With this

```
let scene = Scene(size: self.view.frame.size)
sceneView.presentScene(scene)
```

which makes the demo work - but now shows the warning `Unable to load custom class 'Scene' from module '(null)'` in the logs.

Questions are:

1. Why does the starter project not work out of the box - am I correct in changing the Scene line?
2. If so, how do I fix the warning?

## Update

As suggested by ricardopereira updating XCode beta (from beta 2 to beta 4) solved the problem.  Still not sure why beta 2 had the issue with `Scene` class touch events being ignored.  I've also updated the question title with the XCode version so that others having the same problem would quickly diagnose.

Comment: What is `Scene`  Is this something you made?

Comment: I just created a new demo,  you should not change that at all, not sure why the author had a problem.  Only thing I can think of is at some point he had something called GameScene, but apple switched it to just Scene

Comment: Which version of Xcode?

Comment: I had xcode beta 2 - I just switched to beta 4 and it seems to work now.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Scene is not something I made and is part of the xcode starter template - derived from SKScene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Why does the starter project not work out of the box - am I correct in changing the Scene line?

The starter project work just fine out of the box. At least with Xcode Version 9.0 beta 3 (9M174d). I tested it and it compiles successfully.

[image]

> 2. If so, how do I fix the warning?

You should contact te author of that blog because many steps on that article doesn't make sense. The author says "a bug that I encountered when creating this project_", which bug?! What is he talking about?

Comment: the bug I saw was that the on touch behavior didn't happen at all with the code as-is.  I'm upsing xcode beta-2 - will try to use beta 3 and see if it still occurs.